# Update position of seeker (i.e html input type range) while an audio is playing

Tags: javascript, html

I want the range slider automatically change while audio play.

```
<input type="range" name="seek" id="seeker" min="0" max="100" value="0" >
```

```js
let music = new Audio('https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/m/example.mp3');
music.play();
```

```html
<input type="range" name="seek" id="seeker" min="0" max="100" value="0" >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `new Audio()` actually creates a new `<audio>` element (it is just not injected into your DOM), you can still listen to DOM events. For your use-case, you will want to listen to the [`timeupdate` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/timeupdate_event), and get the progress of the play through by dividing the total [`duration`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/duration) of the audio clip with [`currentTime`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/currentTime):

```
music.addEventListener('timeupdate', () => {
  const percent = music.currentTime / music.duration * 100;
  seeker.value = percent;
});
```

However, if you want the users to use the `<input>` element to seek through the audio clip (I assumed that since you named your element `#seeker`), then you will also need to listen to the [`input` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) from the element. You can use simple math to calculate what `currentTime` value you have to set on the audio element.

Here is a proof-of-concept example. I have ensured that `play()` is only triggered by a button click, since most browsers do not autoplay audio files today.

```js
const music = new Audio('https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/m/example.mp3');
const seeker = document.querySelector('#seeker');

music.addEventListener('timeupdate', () => {
  const percent = music.currentTime / music.duration * 100;
  seeker.value = percent;
});

// Allow seeking
seeker.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  music.currentTime = e.target.value / 100 * music.duration;
});

document.querySelector('#play-button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  music.play();
});
```

```html
<input type="range" name="seek" id="seeker" min="0" max="100" value="0">
<button type="button" id="play-button">Play</button>
```